# Add button at the bottom of a view, on top of a slider

Tags: react-native

I am adding a slider to my App with this code

```
<View>

      <SafeAreaView style={HEADER}>
          <SliderBox
              style={{ height: '100%' }}
              currentImageEmitter={index => setCurrentSliderNumber(index)}
              images={data.images}>
           </SliderBox>   
      </SafeAreaView>
</View>
```

this is the result

[image]

I am trying to add a button on the bottom, on top of the slider, so I changed the code this way

```
      <SafeAreaView style={HEADER}>
          <SliderBox
              style={{ height: '100%' }}
              currentImageEmitter={index => setCurrentSliderNumber(index)}
              images={data.images}>
           </SliderBox>   
      </SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Button
          style={styles.signUpButton}
          appearance="ghost"
          status="control"
        >
          Sign Up
        </Button>
      </View>
</View>
```

But the result is not the one expected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Safeareaview is on top of your buttons. Try zIndex

https://docs.expo.dev/ui-programming/z-index/

else post your styling. may position: 'absoulte' will work too